# Loading files from s3 with subfolders with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm trying to load a csv file in pandas from a s3 bucket in aws. Boto3 seems to fall short in providing functionalities for loading files from subfolders. Let's say i have the following path in s3:
bucket1/bucketwithfiles1/file1.csv

How do i specify how to load file1.csv? I know s3 doesn't have a directory structure.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='/bucket1/creditdefault-ff.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
```

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be confusing buckets, folders, and object keys. Your code should look something like this (where key contains both the folder and file name, and bucket contains only the S3 bucket name):

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key='folder1/folder2/filename.csv')
```

Comment: I looked at a number of answers, perhaps I missed the key point on the others, but your answer was clearest, which is - **prepend the fake folder structure to the file, not the bucket**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple files in a Bucket, each one is identified by a Key (which is the path to the file in S3). So, you want to get a dataframe for all the files (all the keys) in a single Bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='my-file-path')

df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
```

In the case you have multiple files, you'll need to combine boto3 methods named list_object_v2 (to get keys in the bucket you specified), and get_object using a loop on retrieved keys to get all your files.

Then, it might be useful to use the Prefix parameter of the list_object_v2 method to filter on a subfolder in your bucket.

It's a bit of code to write each time you need it, so you can find small Python module to do it for you and get extra features like the pandas_aws python package:

```
from pandas_aws import get_client
from pandas_aws.s3 import get_df_from_keys

s3 = get_client('s3') # you can use your boto3 s3 client if you already hase instanciated one

df = get_df_from_keys(s3, "my-bucket", "my-subfolder/", suffix='.csv')
```

Actually, it calls the same boto3 methods but filters results based on the provided suffix. The Dataframe construction is also embedded and based on the storage format.

See the package here: https://github.com/FlorentPajot/pandas-aws